# How to make accordian menu open with button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to open a accordion menu when  'More' button clicked. I have tried but it showing the accordion in first state and when I'm click the button it collapse. What I want is to open the accordian with button clicked and first state it should close.

Please guide me

```
<input id="hide" value="+" src="./img/Mainpage-more-icon.png" type="button" /><br/>
<div id="rightMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>sss</li>
        <li>sss</li>
        <li>sss</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hide').click(
                function() {
                    //show its submenu
                    $("#rightMenu").stop().slideToggle(500);
                }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make it `slideToggle` in the beginning.

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4XvyD/1)

```
$('#rightMenu').stop().slideToggle(500);
$('#hide').click(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $("#rightMenu").stop().slideToggle(500);    
    }
);
```

And please, I don't even know full **JQuery,** but it's simple knowledge that you can maybe find on **[Google.](http://www.google.com)**

Comment: @sanduni_fdo Your welcome, is this what you wanted?  Because you must've wanted it to hide at first instead?

Comment: :yes, this is the one. i want show the button in first instance and once it click only accordian should display. your Fiddle demo is fine for me.

Comment: @sanduni_fdo So is *this* the correct answer or the one you marked as correct?

Comment: both are same right, i checked Pranav Ram's Fiddle demo , it also showing the same result

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your `ready`

```
$("#rightMenu").hide();
```

Or set it's css style to `display:none`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call $("#rightMenu").hide() ... or hide it with css

see this codepen:
http://codepen.io/nathamanath/pen/bwJKn

Answer (score 1):

Set **`display:none`** in css

```
<input id="hide" value="+" src="./img/Mainpage-more-icon.png" type="button" /><br/>
<div id="rightMenu" style="display:none;">
<!--------------------^-------^--------->   
    <ul>
        <li>sss</li>
        <li>sss</li>
        <li>sss</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hide').click(
            function() {
                //show its submenu
                $("#rightMenu").stop().slideToggle(500);
            }
       );
  });
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8eNGX/)

or you can hide that using jquery when the dom is ready,using **`hide()`** method

```
<input id="hide" value="+" src="./img/Mainpage-more-icon.png" type="button" /><br/>
<div id="rightMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>sss</li>
        <li>sss</li>
        <li>sss</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rightMenu").hide();
    $('#hide').click(
            function() {
                //show its submenu
                $("#rightMenu").stop().slideToggle(500);
            }
       );
  });
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8eNGX/1/)